# Unable to install Appium

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Appium on Ubuntu 16.4 and using this [reference site](http://testingalert.com/steps-to-setup-appium-on-ubuntu/)
I'm stuck on `npm install -g appium` command It is showing below errors :

> ```
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /appium/fsevents:
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
> npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-37-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium"
> npm ERR! node v4.2.6
> npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
> npm ERR! file sh
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
>
> npm ERR! appium-windows-driver@0.5.0 install: `node install-npm.js`
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the appium-windows-driver@0.5.0 install script 'node install-npm.js'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the appium-windows-driver package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node install-npm.js
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs appium-windows-driver
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium-windows-driver
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/narendra/npm-debug.log
> npm ERR! code 1
> ```

Can someone please suggest me the way to overcome this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere `node.js` and `npm` was not compatible with the given configuration that why it was creating problem. I have update both and got the successful installation.